# PHP Phalcon Framework how to prevent escape number using phql AND modelsManager?

Tags: php, phalcon

```
$phql = 'SELECT id,username,email FROM Users WHERE active = :active: LIMIT :offset:, :limit:';
$users = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, array('active' => 'Y', 'offset' => 100, 'limit' => 10));
//But Generates the error SQL statement
//SELECT `users`.`id` AS `id`, `users`.`username` AS `username`, `users`.`email` AS `email` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`active` = 'Y' LIMIT '10' OFFSET '100'
```

ANY one help me ? just using $this->modelsManager...,whith $phql to bind numeric parameters.

Comment: works well with Postgres and Phalcon 1.3.2..

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had the chance to test it out, but from the [PHQL](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html), [modelsManager](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/master/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Manager.html), and [Query](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query.html) documentation, it seems that you can enforce it by creating a query rather than executing it straight away, and then executing it with the specific types you want:

```
// Create the query
$phql = 'SELECT id,username,email FROM Users WHERE active = :active: LIMIT :offset:, :limit:';
$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($phql);

// Setup the values to bind
$values = array(
    'active' => 'Y',
    'offset' => 100,
    'limit'  => 10
);
// Setup the type for each value
$types = array(
    'active' => Phalcon\Db\Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
    'offset' => Phalcon\Db\Column::BIND_PARAM_INT,
    'limit'  => Phalcon\Db\Column::BIND_PARAM_INT
);

// Execute the query
$users = $query->execute($values, $types);
```